# FragmentActivity in Adobe AIR ANE

Tags: java, android, actionscript, air-native-extension, ane

A write native extension for android to display "Better pickers" from github. To display components from this library I wrote Activity extends FragmentActivity to get FragmentManager. I include classes from android-support-v4.jar into my project - no result, I try use platform.xml with packagedDependencies tag to include this jar into ane - no result. I can't make this work.

I also try include with

```
jar -uf nativepickers.jar android
```

android-support-v4.jar into my ane jar. It didn't help.
My platform.xml for android-arm :

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/15.0">

<packagedDependencies>
    <packagedDependency>android-support-v4.jar</packagedDependency>
  </packagedDependencies>
  <packagedResources>
    </packagedResources>
</platform>
```

ane compiled ok with no error, size od ane file increases btu still i got this error from logcat:

**Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/insolutions/nativepickers/OpenCalendarPickerActivity; (159)
Link of class 'Lcom/insolutions/nativepickers/OpenCalendarPickerActivity;' failed
Could not find class 'com.insolutions.nativepickers.OpenCalendarPickerActivity', referenced from method com.insolutions.nativepickers.OpenCalendarPicker.call**

My class OpenCalendarPickerActivity:

```
package com.insolutions.nativepickers;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.calendardatepicker.CalendarDatePickerDialog;
import com.doomonafireball.betterpickers.calendardatepicker.CalendarDatePickerDialog.OnDateSetLi stener;

public class OpenCalendarPickerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        CalendarDatePickerDialog calendarDatePickerDialog = CalendarDatePickerDialog.newInstance(new OnDateSetListener() {

  @Override
  public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialog dialog, int year,
  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

  Intent result = new Intent();
  result.putExtra("yearUTC", year);
  result.putExtra("monthUTC", monthOfYear);
  result.putExtra("dateUTC", dayOfMonth);

  setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
  finish();


  }
  }, 2014, 10, 20);
       calendarDatePickerDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
  }
```

I include jar in my android ane project lie this:  fa1.jpg

And I start my Activity with code:

```
package com.insolutions.nativepickers;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;
import com.adobe.fre.FREObject;

public class OpenCalendarPicker implements FREFunction {


static final int SELECT_DATE_RESULT = 10001;  // The request code

@Override
  public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Context appContext = context.getActivity().getApplicationContext();

  int yearUTC = 0,monthUTC=0,dateUTC = 0;
  try
  {
  yearUTC = data[0].getAsInt();
  monthUTC = data[1].getAsInt();
  dateUTC = data[2].getAsInt();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
  Log.e("nativepickers", "Motyla noga!");
  }


  Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, OpenCalendarPickerActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("yearUTC", yearUTC);
  intent.putExtra("monthUTC", monthUTC);
  intent.putExtra("dateUTC", dateUTC);
  context.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_DATE_RESULT);
  return null;
  }

}
```

And I compile ANE with this command:

```
/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\4.7/eclipse/plugins/com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722/AIRSDK/bin/adt -package -target ane NativePickers.ane extension.xml -swc NativePickers.swc -platform Android-ARM -platformoptions platform-android.xml -C android .
```

And my extension.xml file:

```
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/15.0">
    <id>com.insolutions.nativepickers</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
    <platforms>
        <platform name="Android-ARM">
            <applicationDeployment>
                <nativeLibrary>nativepickers.jar</nativeLibrary>
  <initializer>com.insolutions.nativepickers.NativePickers</initializer>
            </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>


    </platforms>
</extension>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I tried everything and then I realeased that the problem is the "android-support-v4.jar", I don't now why, but if you use the jar you have that error, using FragmentActivity or any other class from v4... but I download the "Support Repository" from SDK Manager and then put the java files inside my project, I generate the jar with the java files and... everythings work!!!! :)

And other thing... I don't use the "packagedDependencies" method allways failed my. so I unzip the jar and put the package files inside my jar... I think is better that way, never failed.

I will put a image... but I just register today XD...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with imports.
The solution was to extract classes from android-support-v4.jar, and add them to my jar. You can simply run before creating jar:

```
unzip -oq lib/android-support-v4.jar -d android
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mateuszmackowiak/NativeDialogs

Use this instead of writing everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did but it might produce other issues, I have yet to solve.
This will enable the usage of the -platformoptions and get rid of the litany of errors thrown by FlashBuilder on compilation.

## **Steps:**#

**1. Point your adt to the AIRSDK package**
-1a. this is located at **{*flashbuilder install*}\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\bin**
-1b. append this to your PATH environment variable
--1b-1.Right Click on "Computer"
--1b-2. Select "Properties"
--1b-3. Click "Advanced Settings"
--1b-4. Click "Environment Variables"
--1b-5. Select "PATH" in User Variables
--1b-6. Click "Edit"
--1b-7. Replace former adt path with this path **{*flashbuilder install*}\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\bin**
--1b-8. Click "Ok"
2. **To get rid of the FlashBuilder CompilationErrors you have to edit a few files**
-2a. Goto {flashbuilder install}\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\lib\android\lib\resources\app_entry\res
-2b. Copy this folder to a backup location.
-2c. Go back into folder
-2d. There are a variety of "values" folders here. You will have to perform these changes for all files within all the "values" folders at this location.
-2e. In every strings.xml file replace "string" with "add-resource type="string""
-2f. In every strings.xml file replace "/string" with "/add-resource"
-2g. In every styles.xml file replace "style" with "add-resource type="style""
-2h. In every styles.xml file replace "/style" with "/add-resource"
-2i. Goto {flashbuilder install}\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\lib\
-2i-1. Copy adt.jar to a backup location
-2i-2. Go back to location
-2i-3. Unzip adt.jar
-2i-4. In unzipped jar goto "com\adobe\air\apk"
-2i-5. Open "AndroidManifest_template.xml"
-2i-6. set android:theme to be "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
-2i-7. Save the file
-2i-8. Rezip the and place back at **{*flashbuilder install*}\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flash.compiler_4.7.0.349722\AIRSDK\lib** 

**3.Now you should be able to compile with the -platformoptions and you should be able to find the platform.xml**